# .NET c#: lambda expression and generics to compare two lists of objects

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have this method that works to compare 2 lists of Customer objects, obtaining a list of customers that only exists in A, another list of customers that only exists in B, and a lists of customers that exists (and are equal) in both:

```
public void compareCustomers(List<Customer> customersA, List<Customer> customersB) {

    //items that exists only in A
    var inlyInA = customersA.Where(p => !customersB.Any(l => 
        p.Code == l.Code
        && p.Name == l.Name 
        && p.Age == l.Age 
    ));

    //items that exists only in B
    var onlyInB = customersB.Where(p => !customerA.Any(l =>
        p.Code == l.Code
        && p.Name == l.Name 
        && p.Age == l.Age 
    ));

    //items that exists in both (and are equal
    var equals = CustomersA.Where(p => CustomersB.Any(l =>
        p.Code == l.Code
        && p.Name == l.Name 
        && p.Age == l.Age 
    ));
    //and now for equals, create a list of tuples to pair them 
    var paired = new List<Tuple<Customer, Customer>>();
    foreach (var tA in equals) {
        var itemB = CustomersB.Where(k => 
            k.Code == tA.Code
            && k.Name == tA.Name
            && k.Age== tA.Age
        );
        paired.Add(Tuple.Create(tA, itemB.First()));
    }

    //and now I can return anything needed (not important now)
}
```

but now I want to create a generic method based in this one, so that I can compare different kinds of entities without having to create a similar method for each case (one that works for Customers, Products, Orders...)

The idea is to have a generic method with a signature similar to this, that receives both lists of entities, and also a list with the properties names that should be used to compare:

```
public void compareCustomers<T>(List<T> entitiesA, List<T> entitiesB, List<string> PropNames) {
}
```

I also have this method to get propertyInfo object from each property name as string:

```
public static PropertyInfo GetProp(object src, string propName) {
    return src.GetType().GetProperty(propName);
}
```

But I have no idea how to go from here... any help?

Comment: I think `GetProp()` is a bit too far fetched since you are just replacing a method with a custom method.

Comment: Have any of the answers helped you?  If so, consider picking one of them as your accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Just pass optional custom implementation of `IEqualityComparer<T>` to the method:

```cs
public void TestEquality<T>(IEnumerable<T> x, IEnumerable<T> y, IEqualityComparer<T> comparer = null)
{
    comparer ??= EqualityComparer<T>.Default;
    // use the comparer
}
```

Also it's possible to override [`Equals`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.object.equals) method of the lists items to use default equality comparer:

```cs
public class Customer : IEquatable<Customer>
{
    // Fields, properties, etc

    public bool Equals (Customer other)
    {
        // Implement equality check
    }
    
    public override bool Equals(Object obj) => Equals(obj as Customer);

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // Make sure equal instances return the same value
    }
}
```

You could also use [`Enumerable.SequenceEqual`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.sequenceequal) or [`HashSet`](https://learn.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.hashset-1) methods
to get reliable and fast implementation.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement a `PropertyComparer`:

```
public class PropertyComparer<T> : IEqualityComparer
{
    private HashSet<PropertyInfo> moPropertyInfos;

    public PropertyComparer(List<string> poPropNames)
    {
        //TODO: check if all properties available with T
        this.moPropertyInfos = typeof(T).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Where(item => poPropNames.Contains(item.Name))
            .ToHashSet();
    }

    public bool Equals(object x, object y)
    {
        return this.moPropertyInfos.All(item =>
            Object.Equals(item.GetValue(x), item.GetValue(y)));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(object obj)
    {
        int lnNullHash = "null".GetHashCode();
        int lnHash = lnNullHash;
        foreach (var loInfo in this.moPropertyInfos)
        {
            lnHash = lnHash ^ loInfo.GetValue(obj)?.GetHashCode() ?? lnNullHash;
        }
        return lnHash;
    }
}
```

Then use it:

```
PropertyComparer<Customer> loComparer = new PropertyComparer<Customer>(new List<string>() { "Code", "Name", "Age" });

var inlyInA = customersA.Where(p => !customersB.Any(l =>
    loComparer.Equals(p, l)));
```

Comment: Why are you using a `HashSet<PropertyInfo>`?

Comment: A HashSet ensures that PropertyInfo is unique.

Comment: It isn't possible for the returns to not be unique - you can't have public instance properties with duplicate names, and you are filtering the unique list by `poPropNames` so if `poPropNames` has duplicates, they will show up once in the filtered list. I think `ToList` is better.

Comment: Okay, that's a point. However, for the question it does not matter whether you use a `List<PropertyInfo>` or a `HashSet<PropertyInfo>`

Comment: But for maintenance, it is better to not imply to future readers of the code that the `HashSet` is needed over `List` because you are depending on the additional features of `HashSet`.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the already given answers could be:

```cs
public void compareEntities<T>(List<T> entitiesA,
                               List<T> entitiesB,
                               Func<T, T, bool> equals) {
    //items that exist only in A
    var onlyInA = entitiesA.Where(p => !entitiesB.Any(l => equals(p, l)));

    //...
}
```

This avoids the *reflection*, `.GetProperty` or `.GetProperties`.

But then it will have to be invoked in this way:

```cs
compareEntities(listA, listB, (x, y) => x.SomeProp == y.SomeProp && x.OtherProp == y.OtherProp);
```

In the special case where `T` is a reference type and the default "equals" semantics for the type (which may override `bool Equals(object)` and `GetHashCode()`) is desired, you can just pass a method group that will resolve to the inherited overload `static bool Equals(object, object)`, namely:

```cs
compareEntities(listA, listB, Equals);
```

You can also make an overload that uses the default equality:

```cs
public void compareEntities<T>(List<T> entitiesA, List<T> entitiesB)
  => compareEntities(entitiesA, entitiesB, EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals);
```

and this will work for both reference types and value types.

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming that the reason you haven't picked any of the 3 answers as solving your problem is that they don't, quite, for whatever reason.

Here's another way to do it.

I am assuming that you want to be able to compare entities in an ad-hoc manner, and don't want to develop/set in stone just *one* basis of comparison, *one* set of properties to use. (Although of course you could have multiple `Comparers` that used different sets of properties.)  Perhaps the list of properties to use is input from some other process, involving user selection.

Here's a simple way you can do that.

You proposed a method that looked like this:

```
public void compareCustomers<T>(List<T> entitiesA, List<T> entitiesB, List<string> PropNames) {
}
```

You could do something quite similar, like this (implemented for a single entity):

```
public void compareEntity<T>(
    T entityA, 
    T entityB, 
    params Func<T, object> propertyGets) {
   
    var result = true;
    
    for(var i = 0; i < propertyGets.Length && result; i++) {
       var propGet = propertyGets[i];

       var valueA = propGet(entityA);
       var valueB = propGet(entityB);

       result = (valueA == valueB) && result;
    }
 
    return result;
}
```

You would call this method like this:

```
public void compareEntities<T>(
    List<T> entitiesA, 
    List<T> entitiesB
    params Func<T, object> propertyGets) {
) {

    //items that exists only in A
    var onlyInA = entitiesA.Where(p => !entitiesB.Any(l => compareEntity(p, l, propertyGets));

    //items that exists only in B
    var onlyInB = entitiesB.Where(p => !entitiesA.Any(l => compareEntity(p, l, propertyGets));

    //items that exists in both (and are equal
    var equals = entitiesA.Where(p => entitiesB.Any(l => compareEntity(p, l, propertyGets));

    // subsequent logic
}
```

And then, when you call the method above for a particular class, you'd do it like this:

```
  var result = compareEntities<Customer>(customersA, customersB, cust => cust.Code, cust => cust.Name, cust => cust.Age);
```

An advantage of this is that you can be prompted in Visual Studio for the property names, and you will also be guaranteed that whatever you pass in will indeed be a reference to a property.  And you haven't used Reflection at all!